# How to change the background colour of the spinner on the aciton bar

Tags: java, android, xml, background, android-actionbar

I'm working on an android app and have come across an issue, I have managed to get the list items on the action bar to highlight to the color i want but the 'spinner' area around the item is staying the default blue, does anyone know how i can change this color?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it!

I used this website which allows you set colors etc. for your action bar and then you just put them in your drawables folder and link it up with the style sheet.

I'm not sure if its the cleanest fix but it works.

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:background` within your spinner.

Comment: I have tried that already in my xml, It hasn't worked, could it be something to do with the aciton bar?

Comment: Oh, it could be. I havn't worked with the action bar much to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
(without Sherlok)

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/YourTheme">
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/ab_selector</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/WidgetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="WidgetStyle" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/ab_menu_selector</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not using Action Bar Sherlock :( Also My Styles xml cannot find either of those parents (the first one obviously due to me not using sherlock).